# What is the meaning of ‘one of each’

Tags: partitives

> There are five leaflets - please take one of each.

I don’t understand why ‘each’ follows ‘one of.’ ‘each’ and ‘one’ are both singular.

Comment: *There are five **types** of leaflet - please take one of each **type**.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It's saying to collect one of every category.

"One of each" is correct, and not redundant. "One" refers to how many items your pick from a category. "Each" refers to how many categories you can choose from - in this case, you can take one item from each category available or referred to. "Two of each" would mean two from each category, and so on.

Comment: Doesn’t it mean one of five leaflets?

Comment: One of each relevant category. If they have five stacks of leaflets, you could take one from each of the five stacks. If you're talking to a butcher, and you want to order two steaks and two sausages, you might say something like "Could I have some steaks and sausages? Two of each."